# Error "Invalid pointer dequeued from free list" in swift application

Tags: swift, xcode, crash

I've received a few crash reports from users which point to a piece of code which works fine in my environment.

Error:
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object xxx: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list

All the crashes point to the same piece of code:

```
Thread 4 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: connectQueue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5a63de3e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a77c150 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff5a59a312 abort + 127
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff5a6a8dbf nanozone_error + 502
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff5a69cdac _nano_malloc_check_clear + 410
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff5a69cbf1 nano_malloc + 35
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff5a696201 malloc_zone_malloc + 103
7   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff5a69550b malloc + 24
8   libicucore.A.dylib              0x00007fff5904a0fd ualoc_localizationsToUse + 3572
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff32c65ff2 _CFBundleCreateMutableArrayOfFallbackLanguages + 274
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff32c65d86 _CFBundleCopyPreferredLanguagesInList + 630
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff32cb121a _CFBundleCopyLocalizationsForPreferences + 58
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff32cb11ae CFBundleCopyPreferredLocalizationsFromArray + 94
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff34d71438 +[NSBundle preferredLocalizationsFromArray:] + 17
14  com.mycompany.myapp     0x000000010ac393b0 Date.prettyPrint() + 96 (Preferences.swift:211)
```

I've extended the Date Class and the crash reports are always pointing to this:

```
extension Date {
    func prettyPrint() -> String {

        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0])
```

The code runs fine on all test machines i've tried - I also ran the code hundreds of times using a loop but I cannot find any crash.

What is going on here? What does the error "Invalid pointer dequeued from free list" exactly mean? Could this be a bug with Swift and/or macOS?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: malloc errors are a nasty thing. It could even be that it crashes due to some memory corruption which occurred *somewhere earlier* in your program. – Did you test your program with all memory-related diagnostic options enabled (address sanitizer, guard malloc, ...)?

Comment: Enabled a ton of debug options but i cannot replicate. As this piece of code is completely independent from anything I really do not have a clue where to start searching. May this be the result of a bit-flip in memory or some kind of memory module problem?

Comment: What happens if you change the implementation of your `Date.prettyPrint()`? If you change the code and still get similar crash reports it means as Martin said that the source of the bug is not there. Anyway it could help you eliminate possibilities and narrow down what you have to inspect.

Comment: It is the only option I have - but it is quite unsatisfying randomly changing working code and hope to prevent random crashes... The affected code does not read any kind of memory from the app just calls native API (even without custom parameters)

Comment: @MikeNathas I agree it's unsatisfying. That's the worse kind of bugs indeed. I wish you success in your debugging sessions.